# write an Algorithm for Scenario using Selection sort?

Tags: data-structures

This Scenario was in my final exam but can't write up an algorithm for it.

Everfresh Cattle farm has its annual Big Cattle Contest. Because the Bilal Haleem son Ali, is majoring in computer science, the county hires him to computerize the Big Cattle judging. Each Cattle’s name (string) and weight (integer) are to be read in from the keyboard. The county expects 500 entries this year. The output needed is a listing of the ten heaviest Cattles, sorted from biggest to smallest. Because Ali has just learned some sorting methods in school, he feels up to the task of writing this “pork-gram”. He writes a program to read in all the entries into an array of records, then uses a selection sort to put the entire array in order based on the Cattle Weight member. He then prints the ten largest values from the array. Can you think of a more efficient way to write this program? If so, write the algorithm.

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't a exam solution platform. Share with us what you've implemented and what you're not able to do

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to not sort the 500 entries, you only have to keep track of the top 10 encountered so far, sort it every time a new value is larger than best10[9].

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would not say that this is a C++ question. This actually sounds quite similar to some interview questions. I will assume you care about worst-case running times so will use Big-Oh and we will worry about the general case of `n` is the number of cattle and `k` is the number of entries we want.

The first observation you can make is looking at the running time of the algorithm they have used which is selection sort. It says that the entire array is sorted so the running time will be `O(n^2 + k)`. Since `k < n` in this case, we get `O(n^2)`.

The first observation to make is that we don't need to sort the entire array only get the `k` largest. In fact, if we're running selection sort to choose maximums, we have this after only `k` iterations of the algorithm giving a running time of `O(kn)`. This may have been enough for the exam question, but we can simplify further.

The next observation extends from the observation that we only care about the `k` largest elements we have encountered so far. Let us say we have this collection of elements when we encounter a new element, we need to determine if it should be within that collection. It actually suffices to show that if it is greater than the smallest element of the collection, then we know that it must be in the collection.

Now, the question now becomes which data structure should we use to store this? Since we care about fast insertions, deletions of the smallest and getting of the smallest, the natural choice is a Min-Heap. Performing at most `n` operations on this heap each costing `log k`, the maximum size of the heap, gives us `O(n log k)` time.

There are some further minor improvements we can make which actually reduce this to `O((n - k) log k)`, though I will leave it as an exercise to you to work out why this is. You should also note that the question asks for the output in sorted order, so you would have to deconstruct the heap at the end taking an additional `O(k log k)` steps.

In terms of the code, this will also be left to you, so best of luck.

p.s. homework / exam questions aren't the most welcome here and there are plenty of sources.